# Getting rid of the line across the graph with modular plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, modulus

I am using the following python script to plot some data

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

t = np.linspace(0, 25, 501)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.mod(t, 2*np.pi), np.sin(t-np.pi/4))
plt.show()
```

See that annoying line that runs from about (2*pi, -0.7) to about (0, -0.65)? I want to be able to not show that while not messing up the rest of the graph. And I need this to be a 2D plot, so cylindrical plotting isn't an option for me here. How do I do this? I tried changing the linestyle, but that did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're applying [`mod`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.mod.html) (modulus, not modular) to your `t` variable which force it so be between the values of 0 and 2*pi. This causes the plot to "go back" to the left several times (once per multiple of 2*pi). If you remove the `mod` and simply plot using `t` for the dependent variable, you'll get the following.

```
plt.plot(t, np.sin(t-np.pi/4))
```

[image]

If this isn't what you want and you *actually* want only the partial sine wave produced by your code, you could do something like the following and replace the last point before the wrap with a NaN which will break the plotting line.

```
tt = mod(t, np.pi * 2)
tt[np.diff(tt) < -6] = np.nan
plt.plot(tt, np.sin(t-np.pi/4));
```

[image]